# SVN unversioned directory with same name already exists

Tags: svn, revert, svn-update

I also see questions with similar headings but this one has exception that error is while updating on server so can't delete the previous unversioned directory.

I am using SVN for uploading code files, you we created uploaded images directory at server manually and don't commit upload images through svn as it is user content that can be different at server and local machines depends upon data in database.

Accidently someone have committed that uploads/images directory so I am having following issue:

```
svn: Failed to add directory 'assets/uploads/images': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists
```

I know why this happened , it is because there were unversioned files at same location, so my question is that how can I fix it?

I don't want to remove remote directory as it contains images related to server database records. So how can I revert that committed directory? I tried
 svn->revert modification->revert previous
commits in that directory but that gives following error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [341:448]; try updating first
```

So any idea, how can I fix it?
In case of any problem in understanding question just drop comment for me and I will make that clear.

thanks

Answer (score 15):

What I tend to do is just rename the offending directory and then re-get from svn. After that I just merge the folders back together.

Comment: Worked perfectly, I had to move the folder away from this location.

Answer (score 3):

I found same problem..and the solution is..
remove assets/uploads/images directory and then get svn up...

Comment: He stressed that he can't delete the directory!

Comment: Why not just renaming it?! Just as Qpirate said?! In my case the backup might took about 9GB in size. It's not easy to backup such huge directory in local.

Comment: I just trying to put different ways to solve it..
Qpirate way also preferable..it's same thing either you renaming it or get backup and delete original, in both case you need extra 9GB.
I heard same problem so many times..but in my case data size is not large.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just use svn up --force  and that solves problem w/o dir copy and remerge...